# Removing interval limit for Color ramp in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, color-ramp

I am Making a program for a DEM I have made, but I have a problem. There is banding in the Color-ramp I have exported from ArcMap, and I can see the individual colors change in the scale. I have set the interval as 50,000 but it still does not export as an HD gradient.

How can I remove the interval cap, so that the [image: Choppy Scale] Scale can be more of a gradient that does not show color banding?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Range Adjustment:
https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/07/26/image-analysis-window-what-is-dra/

You can also try and manually adjust your color ramp:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/editing-the-color-ramp-for-a-raster.htm

You might be out of luck. The scale that you want to visualize the scale bar is quite large and it might just be a limitation of raster symbology in ESRI software.